# How to create dynamic filter in spring boot webflux?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have created a REST API for getting users based on email, type, role ,username and so on ...

**Controller**:

```
@GetMapping("/users/filter")
public Flux<Users> getUsers(
            @RequestParam("email") String query1,
            @RequestParam("type") String query2) {

       return userRepository.filterByQuery(query1, query2);
}
```

**Repository**:

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Users, String>, 
   @Query("{ \"$or\":[ {\"email\": ?0}, {\"type\": ?1} ] }")
   Flux<Users> findByQuery(String query1, String query2);
}
```

The result i am getting is correct. based on below query.

```
 <host>/users/filter?email=user1@learning.com&type=0
```

**Problem**:    How to make it dynamic, so that frontend developer can pass any number of query parameters like

```
<host>/users/filter?email=user1@learning.com&type=0&role=MENTOR
<host>/users/filter?email=user1@learning.com&type=0&role=MENTOR&username=user1
...
```

I am using , Spring with webflux and mongodb

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

so you can make a dynamic filter, you must first place the required option = false in the @RequestParam

```java
@GetMapping("/users/filter")
    public Flux<Users> getUsers(
            @RequestParam("email") String query1,
            @RequestParam("type") String query2,
            @RequestParam(name = "role", required = false) String role,
            @RequestParam(name = "username", required = false) String username) {

        return userRepository.filterByQuery(query1, query2,role,username);
    }
```

then in the service you do if if the parameters arrive null and then you make the queries in mongoReactiveRepository